# How to compare input field with variable on submit in php?

Tags: php, php-7

I have created a random string and using it as captcha but not able to validate. I am very noob in PHP. here I used `isset($_POST['submit'])` but without a click on submit this form is showing error (variable) (strCaptcha is required). My logic is that on submit click code will compare the value of 'strCaptcha' with `$str` and show error or run the form.

```
$error = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (empty($_POST["strCaptcha"]) || $_POST["strCaptcha"] != $str) {
    $error = "strCaptcha is required";
   }
}
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" >
    <p><label><b>COA Number:</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="number" class="text"><br><be>
    <span id="realcap" style="visibility:hidden;"><?php echo implode(' ',str_split($str)); ?></span><be>
    <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $error; ?></span><br>
    <img src="" id="captch" alt="This Is a CAPTCHA Image"><br>
    <label><b>Enter the text of the image above:</b></label><br>
    <input name="strCaptcha" type="text" class="text" value="" maxlength="5"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="awesome medium" name="submit" value="Verify Now"></p>
</form>
```

Added Image

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script>
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("realcap"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      document.getElementById("captch").setAttribute("src", screenshot);
    }
  });
</script>
```

random string

```
$n=5; 
function getName($n) { 
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 
    $randomString = ''; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) { 
        $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1); 
        $randomString .= $characters[$index]; 
    } 
    return $randomString; 
} 

$str = getName($n);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the random string you show is the same as the one you get when doing the form submit?

Comment: I don't see a path for the image and neither where you add the value of the captcha to the $str variable ....

Comment: @davidmpaz random string only changes when a page refresh so at that time on submitting how to compare my input value with $str

Comment: @Vidal i have edited my code, please check

Comment: _“but without a click on submit this form is showing errors”_ - **what** errors? Be specific, and if you are talking about messages issued by PHP itself, quote them _verbatim_ - no one here knows what you are on about, if you just say “is showing errors”.

Comment: Since you have shown multiple code blocks, without saying how exactly they interact, we can not know where `$action` and `$str` in that first block are supposed to come from - so you might be getting undefined variable errors for those. Either way, give us _proper_ information, instead of letting us guess.

Comment: @CBroe no here error means my variable `$error`

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, go and do that first of all. And where $action and $str are supposed to come from in that first code block, is still unclear.

Comment: That this shows you the captcha error message before you even clicked the submit button (so on initial load of the form, via GET), is rather impossible here - you only set that error message inside the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` block, and there is no reasonable explanation why that should be true, if you did not even submit the form yet. (Unless there’s more you didn’t tell us, like that the initial display of the form is also triggered via a POST request sending that parameter to begin with, or anything like that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can be very easy cheated if you are providing the captcha value as plain text in a hidden field on the html.

You have to create the random string and save the value into a session, by doing this the value is not expose to the user and you can use it later for comparison.

Page Code

```
<?php 
session_start();
$captcha = $_SESSION['captcha'];
$error = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (empty($_POST["strCaptcha"]) || $_POST["strCaptcha"] != $captcha) {
    $error = "strCaptcha is required";
   }
}
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" >
    <p><label><b>COA Number:</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="number" class="text"><br>
    <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $error; ?></span><br>
    <img src="image.php" id="captch" alt="This Is a CAPTCHA Image"><br>
    <label><b>Enter the text of the image above:</b></label><br>
    <input name="strCaptcha" type="text" class="text" value="" maxlength="5"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="awesome medium" name="submit" value="Verify Now"></p>
</form>
```

The image have to be generated on the server side.

Example not tested. image.php

```
<?php 
$n=5; 
function getName($n) { 
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 
    $randomString = ''; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) { 
        $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1); 
        $randomString .= $characters[$index]; 
    } 
    return $randomString; 
} 


$str = getName($n);
session_start();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $str;

// Generate image using the $str to create the image.
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $str, $textcolor);

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: the thing is this is WordPress template so I can not start session here

Comment: I did not see anywhere on the post that this is a word press.... Also if you are writing php code you can start the session.  https://www.php.net/session_start

Comment: no not working, is there any way so I can do this on single page

Comment: how are you going to create the image? if you use a JavaScript library it defeat the purpose of a captcha. find a way to create the image on the server side and your problem is solved.